# How to move or reopen; question relates to both ServerFault and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, off-topic

My [question on slow mysql performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/1017604/quickly-find-first-last-row-in-table) was closed as off-topic:

> Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information
>   technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user
>   computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about
>   development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack
>   Overflow.

At this point it is not clear the database performance is slow because of an application/programming problem (so Stack Overflow), or misconfiguration of mysql (ServerFault?). [Rick James](https://serverfault.com/users/503422/rick-james), especially, was providing some excellent advice until the question was closed.

If, indeed, the question is better on Stack Overflow, could someone kindly move it there?

Otherwise, four minutes for an mysql query is a serious problem for us and we're searching hard for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I undeleted the question as it got caught into roomba strangely almost like 10 minutes only after you posted this question.

I didnt voted for the closure, but as I seen the past vote was close. It was almost migrated to dba.stackexchange.com. It was a 50/50 for the close reason.

For me the question is, it's more for **SO** or **DBA** ? Let us know where you would prefer for a migration. For the SQL settings/query you will be better answered on DBA, while if the problem is a bad programmation it would be on SO.

Comment: Thanks for that!  The slow DB response is not a programming problem per se.  The *query* is slow, whether executed via a program (written in various programming languages) or whether typed in on the command line.  I wasn't aware of DBA until now.  Probably a better place for the question.

Comment: @Danny It’s now migrated to DBA.